# Replacing 8 red balls with blue balls

Tags: probability, markov-chains

You have a bag with 8 red balls in it.

Every turn you randomly select a ball from the bag. If it is red you replace it with a blue ball, and if it is blue you replace it with a red ball.

What is the expected number of turns you need to make before all 8 balls in the bag are blue?

If the answer is $\frac{a}{b}$, where a and b are coprime positive integers, what is $a+b$?

---

My Approach:

$E_n$ is the expected number of moves given that you have $n$ blue balls

$E(7) = \frac{1}{8}(1) + \frac{7}{8}[1 + E(6)]$

$E(6) = \frac{2}{8}[1 + E(7)] + \frac{6}{8}[1 + E(5)]$

$E(5) = \frac{3}{8}[1 + E(6)] + \frac{5}{8}[1 + E(4)]$

$E(4) = \frac{4}{8}[1 + E(5)] + \frac{4}{8}[1 + E(3)]$

$E(3) = \frac{5}{8}[1 + E(4)] + \frac{3}{8}[1 + E(2)]$

$E(2) = \frac{6}{8}[1 + E(3)] + \frac{2}{8}[1 + E(1)]$

$E(1) = \frac{7}{8}[1 + E(2)] + \frac{1}{8}[1 + E(0)]$

$E(0) = \frac{8}{8}[1 + E(1)] $

But in this way it doesn't seem to go well.

Comment: A suggestion: To get an idea of what's involved, cut the number of balls from $8$ all the way down to $1$, which is trivial, then try $2$, then $3$, and so on. See if any sort of pattern emerges.

Comment: Solve the subproblem: find the expected time to get one more blue ball than what you started with ($0,1,\dots,7$ blue balls), and apply strong Markov.  In other words, look at what you can say about $E(n)-E(n+1)$ first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not finding anything wrong in the equations.

Putting it in a Jordan- Gauss calculator, I get an answer of $\dfrac{a}{b}= \dfrac{32768}{105}$

Thus $a+b= 32873$

The calculator is [here](https://matrix.reshish.com/gaussSolution.php)

I strongly advise you to check the computations.